# How to decide right time to start using read replica in MySQL

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, mysql-replication, rds

I have an ecommerce website with around 30,000 daily users with over 50,000 sessions. We are using RDS m5.xlarge instance. We are not facing any issues as such in read or write operations on day to day basis. But occasionally we face following challenges:

- On somedays due to sale or aggressive marketing we get more than double users, at such times we have CPU hitting 100% for several times during day
- Very Occasionaly, while some heavy write in progress then read becomes slow

Looking at this, I am not able to make a judgment whether I should further vertically scale up RDS instance or spin up a read replica. Two points which I want to consider while making this decision:

- Will having a read replica, help me in removing need to further vertically space DB on high traffic days?
- Can I lower or keep the cost same with a read replica along while achieving more scalability.

At an average I have following usage on m5.xlarge instance:

- CPU usage 40%
- DB connections 100
- RAM 6 GB used
- 125 Write IOPS
- 3 Read IOPS

It appears to be very low usage except CPU, is read replica a way to achieve greater scalability without increasing cost?

Comment: High CPU almost always implies inefficient queries.  Set `long_query_time = 1`. 
 Then post the slowlog from a busy hour.  We can probably advise on how to improve the queries (via indexing, reformulation, etc), thereby delaying the need to add read replicas.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you need is an auto-scaling RDS, which unfortunately doesn't exist for compute.

**Increase RDS Size**

If you increase your instance size you pay more 24/7. It's the simplest solution, and should reduce many of your problems. If the cost isn't an issue this is probably the best issue.

**Read Replica**

The other major option is a read replica. You would have to modify your software to use a read replica, as it will have a different endpoint to the main database URL. You might for example send all writes to the main database, and all reads to the read replica. The read replica can be slightly behind the updates from the master. You may even be able to reduce the size of the main database - but you will need to benchmark or be conservative with your approach.

You could consider having a read replica spun up manually before any expected major events. This would be manual and would take some time, and your application would have to cope with a database that is sometimes, but not always, there.

**Caching**

Depending on your access patterns, caching data in Redis / Memcached could potentially reduce the database load enough that you don't need to update your database. This of course relies on having to read the same data more than once, and having sufficient cache storage.

**Aurora**

You could consider [Amazon Aurora for MySQL](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/). I haven't used it myself, but it's meant to scale very well - though each individual transaction may not be quite as fast as standard RDS.

**Database Optimization**

Another option is to look at what is taking database capacity and optimizing "expensive" queries, or indexes. If you have simple queries and it's just high load that might not help.